# Selección aleatoria de una fila devuelve mas de 1 resultado

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estoy intentando generar un *apellido*, resultado de sumar 2 palabras aleatorias.

La tabla que guarda las palabras es:

```
CREATE TABLE lastnames(
  label VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY( `id` )
);
```

Esta tabla está rellena con 100 palabras. Eso es correcto, y un `SELECT id, label FROM lastnames ORDER BY id;` muestra correctamente su contenido, sin `id` duplicados ni nada *raro*:

> >select min( id ) from lastnames; --> 1
>   >select max( id ) from lastnames; --> 100
>   >select count( * ) from lastnames; --> 100

Ahora, estoy intentando crear una función que me genere una cadena, como la suma de 2 palabras aleatorias de la tabla anterior. De momento, me conformo con obtener **1** palabra aleatoria:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS generate_lastname $$
CREATE FUNCTION generate_lastname( ) RETURNS VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE lastname_max INTEGER DEFAULT ( SELECT count( * ) FROM lastnames );
  DECLARE ln1 VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT ( SELECT label FROM lastnames WHERE id = ( floor( rand( ) * lastname_max ) + 1 ) );

  RETURN ln1;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

No muestra ningún error de sintaxis, pero al probarlo genera un error

> select generate_lastname( );
>   ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Dicho error **no se genera siempre**. Algunas veces la función devuelve el valor esperado, y otras muestra el error. Aproximadamente el 50% de las veces.

La tabla `lastnames` **no ha sido modificada** en ningún momento.

- ¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Estoy usando:

> >mysql --version
>   mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.17-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

<sub>Finalmente encontré una solución alternativa, usando `ORDER BY rand( )`, pero la pregunta original sigue en pié: ¿ Cúal es el problema de mi código ?</sub>

Comment: ¿Es MariaDB or MySQL? Hoy en día estas bases de datos ya no son equivalentes.

Comment: Es MariaDB. No estaba seguro de que etiqueta poner, ni si eran compatibles en esto :-/

Comment: Salvo funciones JSON, y alguna en especial tal vez como clusters... la mayor parte de lo que funciona en MySQL es portable a MariaDB así que técnicamente las 2 etiquetas son válidas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para asegurar que la consulta:

```
SELECT label FROM lastnames WHERE id = ( floor( rand( ) * lastname_max ) + 1 )
```

Siempre produzca una sola fila, yo la reemplazaría por:

```
SELECT label FROM lastnames ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Creé un ejemplo ejecutable en [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bMrxEQex1y8bZUf3uXmRmn/0). Si lo ejecutas varias veces, vas a ver que entrega filas distintas aleatoriamente.

**Edición para aclarar la selección de múltiples filas**

Tu ejemplo puede entregar múltiples filas porque el predicado:

```
id = floor( rand( ) * (SELECT count( * ) FROM lastnames) )
```

no es evaluado una sola vez, sino que es evaluado tantas veces como filas tenga la tabla. En tu caso, el predicado es "ejecutado" 100 veces. Al ejecutarlo 100 veces puede evaluar como `verdadero` en cero, una o más veces; por lo tanto, selecciona cero, una o más filas. Espero que la explicación sea clara.

Ejemplo ejecutable en [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bMrxEQex1y8bZUf3uXmRmn/1). Si lo ejecutas varias veces vas a ver que algunas veces no selecciona nada, otras veces una fila, y otras veces más de una.

Comment: +1 y gracias por la respuesta. Lo que sugieres ya lo hice (lo pongo al final de la pregunta, en letra pequeña). Sin embargo, me interesa mucho saber el porque mi primer intento genera mas de una fila, cuando es 100% seguro que no hay filas duplicadas.

Comment: @Trauma Agregué la explicación.